# How to get auto-resizing textarea passed as props? Works on it's own, but not as a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vuejs2, textarea

I am working on a new component for textareas and want to give them the ability to do three things; `autofocus`, `debounce` (still working on that) and `autogrow/resize` based on value.

I have been given a base component on which to work with and there are a few computed properties that I have been given that I'm not too familar with. From what I understand though, I shouldnt need them to be able to make these new props work.

I have the autofocus working perfectly as a passed prop, but the autogrow/resize has been giving me some trouble. In an isolated instance, I can get it to work, but passed as a prop with this basecomponent, I cannot managed to get it working.

When I try and add `:value="value"` for the v-model to work, I get an error:

**`:value="value" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally`**

I imagine this is because it's clashing with the `v-model="model"` above, but I'm not sure what to do with it from there.

I've attached the version that does work at the bottom.

My question is, what am I doing wrong in the CcInput-App.vue relation that won't make it work like the isolated version below?

[Here's a link to the github repo as well!](https://github.com/LovelyAndy/lovely-textareas)

If you need anymore information please do not hesitate to ask!

***CcInput***

```
<template>
  <div class="cc-input">
    <input
      v-if="propsToPass.type !== 'textarea'"
      v-bind="propsToPass"
      v-model="model"
      ref="input"
    />
    <textarea
      v-if="propsToPass.type === 'textarea'"
      v-bind="propsToPass"
      v-model="model"
      ref="textarea"
    />
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'CcInput',
  props: {
    /** v-model */
    value: { type: [String, Number], default: '' },
    valueType: { type: [String, undefined], default: undefined },
    autofocus: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    autogrow: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.autofocus) {
      if (this.propsToPass.type !== 'textarea') {
        this.focusInput()
      } else {
        this.focusTextArea()
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      innerValue: this.value,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    focusInput() {
      this.$refs.input.focus()
    },
    focusTextArea() {
      this.$refs.textArea.focus()
    },
  },
  computed: {
    listenersWithoutInput() {
      return { ...this.$listeners, input: undefined }
    },
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        const { propsToPass } = this
        if (propsToPass.type === 'number') {
          const valAsNumberIfNotNaN = !isNaN(Number(val)) ? Number(val) : val
          this.$emit('input', valAsNumberIfNotNaN)
          return
        }
        this.$emit('input', val)
      },
    },
    propsToPass() {
      const { $attrs, valueType } = this
      const type = $attrs.type ? $attrs.type : valueType === 'number' ? 'number' : undefined
      return { ...$attrs, type }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass">
.cc-input
  min-width: 0
  max-width: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: nowrap
  align-items: center
  position: relative
  textarea, input
    padding: 10px
    min-width: 0
    width: 100%
    min-height: 24px
    line-height: 24px
    outline: none
    box-shadow: none
    -webkit-appearance: none
    border: none
    z-index: 2
    position: relative
.cc-input
  min-width: 0
  max-width: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: nowrap
  align-items: center
  position: relative
  textarea, input
    padding: 10px
    min-width: 0
    width: 100%
    min-height: 24px
    line-height: 24px
    outline: none
    box-shadow: none
    -webkit-appearance: none
    border: none
    z-index: 2
    position: relative
    background: none
  textarea
    box-sizing: border-box
    min-height: 100px !important

  &::after, &::before
    border-radius: 4px
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    bottom: 0
    left: 0
    right: 0
    content: ''
    border-style: solid
    transition: border-color 300ms ease
  &::after
    border-width: 1px
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)
  &::before
    border-width: 2px
    border-color: transparent
  &:focus-within::after
    border-color: transparent
  &:focus-within::before
    border-color: purple
</style>
```

***App.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="textarea">
        autofocus
        <CcInput valueType="textarea" :autofocus="true" />
      </div>
      <div class="textarea">
        debounce
        <CcInput valueType="textarea" :debounce="300" />
      </div>
      <div class="textarea">
        autogrow
        <CcInput valueType="textarea" :autogrow="true" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CcInput from '../components/CcInput.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CcInput,
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
*
  width: 50vw
  left: 50%
.textarea
  text-align: center
</style>
```

***Autogrow.vue***

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea class="textarea" name="body" id="body" @input="autogrow($event)"></textarea>
    <textarea class="textarea" name="anotherbody" id="anotherbody"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Autogrow',
  },
  methods: {
    autogrow(e) {
      e.target.style.height = 'auto'
      e.target.style.height = `${e.target.scrollHeight}px`
    },
  },
}
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.textarea
  box-sizing: border-box
  width: 100%
  padding: 20px
  border-radius: 8px
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the `propsToPass` computed property, where it [defaults `type` to `undefined` when `valueType` is not `"number"`](https://github.com/LovelyAndy/lovely-textareas/blob/a1c5835/src/components/CcInput.vue#L94):

```js
// Ccinput.vue
export default {
  computed: {
    propsToPass() {
      const { $attrs, valueType } = this
      const type = $attrs.type ? $attrs.type : valueType === 'number' ? 'number' : undefined
      return { ...$attrs, type }
    },
  }
}
```

Given a `valueType` of `"textarea"`, `propsToPass.type` is `undefined`, which does not satisfy [the condition required to render the textarea](https://github.com/LovelyAndy/lovely-textareas/blob/a1c5835/src/components/CcInput.vue#L12) with the autogrow behavior:

```html
<textarea v-if="propsToPass.type === 'textarea'" ... />
```

One way to fix this is to update the condition to check `valueType` instead of `propsToPass.type`:

```html
<textarea v-if="valueType === 'textarea'" ... />
```

and update [`propsToPass.type` reference](https://github.com/LovelyAndy/lovely-textareas/blob/a1c5835/src/components/CcInput.vue#L43) to use `valueType`:

```js
// if (this.propsToPass.type !== 'textarea') {

if (this.valueType !== 'textarea') {
```

As an aside, you have a [typo in `this.$refs.textArea`](https://github.com/LovelyAndy/lovely-textareas/blob/a1c5835/src/components/CcInput.vue#L67):

```js
// this.$refs.textArea.focus()  ❌
                  ^

this.$refs.textarea.focus() ✅
```